# C# LINQ to SQL Specified type member inside lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, asp.net-web-api

I understand that LINQ can't use properties that are not mapped to a database column, though I don't understand why one LINQ statement works inside a non static method but I get this error when attempting within one.

Here's my **working** method:

```
private TemplatesAPIContext db = new TemplatesAPIContext();

// GET api/Template
public IQueryable<TemplateDto> GetTemplates()
{
    return db.TemplateModels.Include(t => t.Categories).Select(
        x => new TemplateDto
        {
            TemplateID = x.TemplateID,
            Name = x.Name,
            HTMLShowcase = x.HTMLShowcase,
            ShortDescription = x.ShortDescription,
            CreationDate = x.CreationDate,
            Downloads = x.Downloads,
            Tags = x.Tags,
            Categories = db.CategoryModels
                            .Where(c => x.Categories.Where(a => a.TemplateID == x.TemplateID)
                            .Select(a => a.CategoryID).Contains(c.CategoryID))
        }
    );
}
```

I don't want to repeat myself with this complex building of a DTO (I actually still need to add some other relationships still to it and it will get much more complex) and type this out on every method in the controller so I wanted to make a lambda expression and pass it to the methods.

So I did this:

```
private static readonly Expression<Func<TemplateModel, TemplateDto>> AsTemplateDto =
    x => new TemplateDto
    {
        TemplateID = x.TemplateID,
        Name = x.Name,
        HTMLShowcase = x.HTMLShowcase,
        ShortDescription = x.ShortDescription,
        CreationDate = x.CreationDate,
        Downloads = x.Downloads,
        Tags = x.Tags,
        Categories = new TemplatesAPIContext().CategoryModels
                            .Where(c => x.Categories.Where(a => a.TemplateID == x.TemplateID)
                            .Select(a => a.CategoryID).Contains(c.CategoryID))
    };
```

In the hopes of calling:

```
// GET api/Template
public IQueryable<TemplateDto> GetTemplates()
{
    return db.TemplateModels.Include(t => t.Categories).Select(AsTemplateDto);
}
```

But this returns this error, which doesn't make sense to me since its the exact same query, only difference being that I need to instantiate the dbContext in the lambda since I can't use the one instantiated in the controller as the lambda expression is static.

#### Error

> The specified type member 'CategoryModels' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: You're trying to query another context from one? Anyway, EF cannot translate that method into SQL query (how do you think it would be?)

Comment: What is throwing me is that it works inside the first example. I suppose what I am asking is, how would it be possible to write the lambda expression to result in the same query as the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important that the same context be used within the query as the one that's making the query, for the query provider to understand what you're trying to do.  So all you need is a way of making a copy of that expression that's specific to a given context, which isn't that hard, you've done almost all of the work.

```
//TODO rename method as appropriate
private static Expression<Func<TemplateModel, TemplateDto>> 
    CreateTemplateDTO(TemplatesAPIContext context)
{
    return x => new TemplateDto
    {
        TemplateID = x.TemplateID,
        Name = x.Name,
        HTMLShowcase = x.HTMLShowcase,
        ShortDescription = x.ShortDescription,
        CreationDate = x.CreationDate,
        Downloads = x.Downloads,
        Tags = x.Tags,
        Categories = context.CategoryModels
            .Where(c => x.Categories.Where(a => a.TemplateID == x.TemplateID)
            .Select(a => a.CategoryID).Contains(c.CategoryID))
    };
}
```

Now you can write:

```
public IQueryable<TemplateDto> GetTemplates()
{
    return db.TemplateModels.Include(t => t.Categories)
        .Select(CreateTemplateDTO(db));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought I tried passing the context as a parameter to the expression and it gave me some errors, let me try it again.

Comment: @francisco.preller You almost certainly won't be able to do it as a field; it'll need to be a method, or at best a property, but a method would be best.

Comment: ah got it, had to actually turn it into a method instead of just a property. Thanks, this worked like a charm. Man I was so close ><

Comment: @francisco.preller Yeah, I almost feel bad taking credit for a solution when you'd done 95% of the work.

Comment: I felt bad having to ask, but I had been banging my head since last night on it :P

Comment: @francisco.preller did that work on real data? (really interesting)

Comment: @jim Why are you surprised?  Other than a bit of extra code for the closure object (which the query provider is more than capable of handling properly) the resulting expression in this answer vs the working solution in the question is the same.

Comment: @jim Yes it certainly did, as it was on the first segment where I showed the working code. The problem is that when I made the lambda, I was passing in a TemplateModel instead of the context. As you can see above, what also needed to happen was to pass the actual context in as a parameter

Comment: @jim I think you may be confused because you haven't seen the models. My TemplateModel and TemplateDto both have matching data structures which link them together through a linking table behind the scenes.

Comment: @Servy i doubted because L2EF often doesnt like passing custom funcs (like CreateTemplateDTO(db)). I worked with EF much, but still not sure for some points :( ok, that's grate for it's working. Never mind.

Comment: @jim The point is it's not passing in an expression that calls the func; `item =>  CreateTemplateDTO(db)` would fail miserably.  The function is called eagerly *to create the expression that the query provider will use*.

Comment: @Servy yes, you're absolutely right. I just need some better understanding of expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your first method is a simple expression tree that contains only simple operations in tree nodes (like assign A to B) thus it can easily be compiled into SQL query.
The other method contains instantiation of TemplatesAPIContext. It's not possible for database query.